# Nvd3: How prevent to display chart between -1 and 1 if have all y values 0?

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, nvd3.js

Have a little modified version of linePlusBarChart model(), when pass data that has all y values setted to zero Y axis show me a range between 1 and -1. Is possible to set a range between 0 and 1?

Have tried with `chart.yAxis.scale().domain([0]);` and `chart.forceY([0])` but nothing.

Comment: You need to pass a two-element array to `forceY` -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766879/d3-js-nvd3-js-how-to-set-y-axis-range

Comment: have tried but nothing, problem still present

Comment: could you put your code on JSFiddle

Comment: I should have said, my issue is with the `stackedAreaChart`, where apparently `yDomain` doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

`forceY` forces the domain to include the values you pass in, it doesn't shrink the domain created from the data.  To set a specific domain, you set `chart.yDomain([0,1])`.  However, that would set the domain to [0,1] regardless of what your data is.  As I understand it, you only want to change the behaviour when all your y-values are 0.

For that, try `chart.forceY([1])`.  Now, when NVD3 tries to figure out the domain, it will see both the zero values from the data *and* the 1 from the force statement.  So it will have a valid domain and it won't have to make up a domain by adding and subtracting 1 from the data value.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the example provided by the [nvd3 site example linePlusBarChart](http://nvd3.org/examples/index.html)

You can insert one line in the javascript

```
chart.lines.forceY([0,1]);
```

[Here is the test code](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CF0FB05DFFCF3740!111&authkey=!AAGYjm04FtsTnQg&ithint=file,.rar)