# Dynamically scaling up y axis range in angular-nvd3 line chart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I am using angular nvd3 directives [here](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) to build a multi-line chart. The chart automatically scales the y-axis to the maximum and minimum values among all the series that are plotted. Can I change this to perhaps 1.5 times the minimum and maximum values instead? Or any other dynamic configuration of my choosing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766879/d3-js-nvd3-js-how-to-set-y-axis-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically change the Y-Axis based on data, one way would be to assign the `getMaxValue(*list*)` result to a variable, if you have your data in a JSON array. For example:

```
var maxValue = *dataUtil*.getMaxValue(datalist);
```

then you would need to use the `forceY` function in nvd3, and assign the upper range to `maxValue`, or whatever you want(1.5 in your case):

```
$scope.optionsBar.chart.forceY = [0, maxValue * 1.5];
```

This will change dynamically change the Y-Axis range based on the highest data value in the data set.

For reference, take a look at my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jp8nOk?p=preview) with this implementation.