# How to draw an upper limit for nvd3.js graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js, interactive

Hey I have build a stacked area chart using nvd3.js. I would like to know if I can create an upper limit for current graph,when the upper limit can be change by choice of the user. If yes, how can I do it properly.
This is the final result which I want to have
[image]

This is the code of my current graph

```js
var data = [
        {
            "key": "TDCG",
            "values": [[1138683600000, 27.38478809681], [1141102800000, 27.371377218208], [1143781200000, 26.309915460827], [1146369600000, 26.425199957521], [1149048000000, 26.823411519395], [1151640000000, 23.850443591584], [1154318400000, 23.158355444054], [1156996800000, 22.998689393694], [1159588800000, 27.977128511299], [1162270800000, 29.073672469721], [1164862800000, 28.587640408904], [1167541200000, 22.788453687638], [1170219600000, 22.429199073597], [1172638800000, 22.324103271051], [1175313600000, 17.558388444186], [1177905600000, 16.769518096208], [1180584000000, 16.214738201302], [1183176000000, 18.729632971228], [1185854400000, 18.814523318848], [1188532800000, 19.789986451358], [1191124800000, 17.070049054933], [1193803200000, 16.121349575715], [1196398800000, 15.141659430091], [1199077200000, 17.175388025298], [1201755600000, 17.286592443521], [1204261200000, 16.323141626569], [1206936000000, 19.231263773952], [1209528000000, 18.446256391094], [1212206400000, 17.822632399764], [1214798400000, 15.539366475979], [1217476800000, 15.255131790216], [1220155200000, 15.660963922593], [1222747200000, 13.254482273697], [1225425600000, 11.920796202299], [1228021200000, 12.122809090925], [1230699600000, 15.691026271393], [1233378000000, 14.720881635107], [1235797200000, 15.387939360044], [1238472000000, 13.765436672229], [1241064000000, 14.6314458648], [1243742400000, 14.292446536221], [1246334400000, 16.170071367016], [1249012800000, 15.948135554337], [1251691200000, 16.612872685134], [1254283200000, 18.778338719091], [1256961600000, 16.75602606542], [1259557200000, 19.385804443147], [1262235600000, 22.950590240168], [1264914000000, 23.61159018141], [1267333200000, 25.708586989581], [1270008000000, 26.883915999885], [1272600000000, 25.893486687065], [1275278400000, 24.678914263176], [1277870400000, 25.937275793023], [1280548800000, 29.46138169384], [1283227200000, 27.357322961862], [1285819200000, 29.057235285673], [1288497600000, 28.549434189386], [1291093200000, 28.506352379723], [1293771600000, 29.449241421597], [1296450000000, 25.796838168807], [1298869200000, 28.740145449189], [1301544000000, 22.091744141872], [1304136000000, 25.079662545409], [1306814400000, 23.674906973064], [1309406400000, 23.41800274293], [1312084800000, 23.243644138871], [1314763200000, 31.591854066817], [1317355200000, 31.497112374114], [1320033600000, 26.672380820431], [1322629200000, 27.297080015495], [1325307600000, 20.174315530051], [1327986000000, 19.631084213899], [1330491600000, 20.366462219462], [1333166400000, 17.429019937289], [1335758400000, 16.75543633539], [1338436800000, 16.182906906042]]
        },
        {
            "key": "Hydrogen",
            "values": [[1138683600000, 7.2800122043237], [1141102800000, 7.1187787503354], [1143781200000, 8.351887016482], [1146369600000, 8.4156698763993], [1149048000000, 8.1673298604231], [1151640000000, 5.5132447126042], [1154318400000, 6.1152537710599], [1156996800000, 6.076765091942], [1159588800000, 4.6304473798646], [1162270800000, 4.6301068469402], [1164862800000, 4.3466656309389], [1167541200000, 6.830104897003], [1170219600000, 7.241633040029], [1172638800000, 7.1432372054153], [1175313600000, 10.608942063374], [1177905600000, 10.914964549494], [1180584000000, 10.933223880565], [1183176000000, 8.3457524851265], [1185854400000, 8.1078413081882], [1188532800000, 8.2697185922474], [1191124800000, 8.4742436475968], [1193803200000, 8.4994601179319], [1196398800000, 8.7387319683243], [1199077200000, 6.8829183612895], [1201755600000, 6.984133637885], [1204261200000, 7.0860136043287], [1206936000000, 4.3961787956053], [1209528000000, 3.8699674365231], [1212206400000, 3.6928925238305], [1214798400000, 6.7571718894253], [1217476800000, 6.4367313362344], [1220155200000, 6.4048441521454], [1222747200000, 5.4643833239669], [1225425600000, 5.3150786833374], [1228021200000, 5.3011272612576], [1230699600000, 4.1203601430809], [1233378000000, 4.0881783200525], [1235797200000, 4.1928665957189], [1238472000000, 7.0249415663205], [1241064000000, 7.006530880769], [1243742400000, 6.994835633224], [1246334400000, 6.1220222336254], [1249012800000, 6.1177436137653], [1251691200000, 6.1413396231981], [1254283200000, 4.8046006145874], [1256961600000, 4.6647600660544], [1259557200000, 4.544865006255], [1262235600000, 6.0488249316539], [1264914000000, 6.3188669540206], [1267333200000, 6.5873958262306], [1270008000000, 6.2281189839578], [1272600000000, 5.8948915746059], [1275278400000, 5.5967320482214], [1277870400000, 0.99784432084837], [1280548800000, 1.0950794175359], [1283227200000, 0.94479734407491], [1285819200000, 1.222093988688], [1288497600000, 1.335093106856], [1291093200000, 1.3302565104985], [1293771600000, 1.340824670897], [1296450000000, 0], [1298869200000, 0], [1301544000000, 0], [1304136000000, 0], [1306814400000, 0], [1309406400000, 0], [1312084800000, 0], [1314763200000, 0], [1317355200000, 4.4583692315], [1320033600000, 3.6493043348059], [1322629200000, 3.8610064091761], [1325307600000, 5.5144800685202], [1327986000000, 5.1750695220792], [1330491600000, 5.6710066952691], [1333166400000, 8.5658461590953], [1335758400000, 8.6135447714243], [1338436800000, 8.0231460925212]]
        },
        {
            "key": "Methane",
            "values": [[1138683600000, 1.544303464167], [1141102800000, 1.4387289432421], [1143781200000, 0], [1146369600000, 0], [1149048000000, 0], [1151640000000, 1.328626801128], [1154318400000, 1.2874050802627], [1156996800000, 1.0872743105593], [1159588800000, 0.96042562635813], [1162270800000, 0.93139372870616], [1164862800000, 0.94432167305385], [1167541200000, 1.277750166208], [1170219600000, 1.2204893886811], [1172638800000, 1.207489123122], [1175313600000, 1.2490651414113], [1177905600000, 1.2593129913052], [1180584000000, 1.373329808388], [1183176000000, 0], [1185854400000, 0], [1188532800000, 0], [1191124800000, 0], [1193803200000, 0], [1196398800000, 0], [1199077200000, 0], [1201755600000, 0], [1204261200000, 0], [1206936000000, 0], [1209528000000, 0], [1212206400000, 0], [1214798400000, 0], [1217476800000, 0], [1220155200000, 0], [1222747200000, 1.4516108933695], [1225425600000, 1.1856025268225], [1228021200000, 1.3430470355439], [1230699600000, 2.2752595354509], [1233378000000, 2.4031560010523], [1235797200000, 2.0822430731926], [1238472000000, 1.5640902826938], [1241064000000, 1.5812873972356], [1243742400000, 1.9462448548894], [1246334400000, 2.9464870223957], [1249012800000, 3.0744699383222], [1251691200000, 2.9422304628446], [1254283200000, 2.7503075599999], [1256961600000, 2.6506701800427], [1259557200000, 2.8005425319977], [1262235600000, 2.6816184971185], [1264914000000, 2.681206271327], [1267333200000, 2.8195488011259], [1270008000000, 0], [1272600000000, 0], [1275278400000, 0], [1277870400000, 1.0687057346382], [1280548800000, 1.2539400544134], [1283227200000, 1.1862969445955], [1285819200000, 0], [1288497600000, 0], [1291093200000, 0], [1293771600000, 0], [1296450000000, 1.941972859484], [1298869200000, 2.1142247697552], [1301544000000, 2.3788590206824], [1304136000000, 2.5337302877545], [1306814400000, 2.3163370395199], [1309406400000, 2.0645451843195], [1312084800000, 2.1004446672411], [1314763200000, 3.6301875804303], [1317355200000, 2.454204664652], [1320033600000, 2.196082370894], [1322629200000, 2.3358418255202], [1325307600000, 0], [1327986000000, 0], [1330491600000, 0], [1333166400000, 0.39001201038526], [1335758400000, 0.30945472725559], [1338436800000, 0.31062439305591]]
        },
        {
            "key": "Acetylene",
            "values": [[1138683600000, 13.356778764352], [1141102800000, 13.611196863271], [1143781200000, 6.895903006119], [1146369600000, 6.9939633271352], [1149048000000, 6.7241510257675], [1151640000000, 5.5611293669516], [1154318400000, 5.6086488714041], [1156996800000, 5.4962849907033], [1159588800000, 6.9193153169279], [1162270800000, 7.0016334389777], [1164862800000, 6.7865422443273], [1167541200000, 9.0006454225383], [1170219600000, 9.2233916171431], [1172638800000, 8.8929316009479], [1175313600000, 10.345937520404], [1177905600000, 10.075914677026], [1180584000000, 10.089006188111], [1183176000000, 10.598330295008], [1185854400000, 9.968954653301], [1188532800000, 9.7740580198146], [1191124800000, 10.558483060626], [1193803200000, 9.9314651823603], [1196398800000, 9.3997715873769], [1199077200000, 8.4086493387262], [1201755600000, 8.9698309085926], [1204261200000, 8.2778357995396], [1206936000000, 8.8585045600123], [1209528000000, 8.7013756413322], [1212206400000, 7.7933605469443], [1214798400000, 7.0236183483064], [1217476800000, 6.9873088186829], [1220155200000, 6.8031713070097], [1222747200000, 6.6869531315723], [1225425600000, 6.138256993963], [1228021200000, 5.6434994016354], [1230699600000, 5.495220262512], [1233378000000, 4.6885326869846], [1235797200000, 4.4524349883438], [1238472000000, 5.6766520778185], [1241064000000, 5.7675774480752], [1243742400000, 5.7882863168337], [1246334400000, 7.2666010034924], [1249012800000, 7.519182132226], [1251691200000, 7.849651451445], [1254283200000, 10.383992037985], [1256961600000, 9.0653691861818], [1259557200000, 9.6705248324159], [1262235600000, 10.856380561349], [1264914000000, 11.27452370892], [1267333200000, 11.754156529088], [1270008000000, 8.2870811422456], [1272600000000, 8.0210264360699], [1275278400000, 7.5375074474865], [1277870400000, 8.3419527338039], [1280548800000, 9.4197471818443], [1283227200000, 8.7321733185797], [1285819200000, 9.6627062648126], [1288497600000, 10.187962234549], [1291093200000, 9.8144201733476], [1293771600000, 10.275723361713], [1296450000000, 16.796066079353], [1298869200000, 17.543254984075], [1301544000000, 16.673660675084], [1304136000000, 17.963944353609], [1306814400000, 16.637740867211], [1309406400000, 15.84857094609], [1312084800000, 14.767303362182], [1314763200000, 24.778452182432], [1317355200000, 18.370353229999], [1320033600000, 15.2531374291], [1322629200000, 14.989600840649], [1325307600000, 16.052539160125], [1327986000000, 16.424390322793], [1330491600000, 17.884020741105], [1333166400000, 7.1424929577921], [1335758400000, 7.8076213051482], [1338436800000, 7.2462684949232]]
        },
        {
            "key": "Ethylene",
            "values": [[1138683600000, 14.212410956029], [1141102800000, 13.973193618249], [1143781200000, 15.218233920665], [1146369600000, 14.38210972745], [1149048000000, 13.894310878491], [1151640000000, 15.593086090032], [1154318400000, 16.244839695188], [1156996800000, 16.017088850646], [1159588800000, 14.183951830055], [1162270800000, 14.148523245697], [1164862800000, 13.424326059972], [1167541200000, 12.974450435753], [1170219600000, 13.23247041802], [1172638800000, 13.318762655574], [1175313600000, 15.961407746104], [1177905600000, 16.287714639805], [1180584000000, 16.246590583889], [1183176000000, 17.564505594809], [1185854400000, 17.872725373165], [1188532800000, 18.018998508757], [1191124800000, 15.584518016603], [1193803200000, 15.480850647181], [1196398800000, 15.699120036984], [1199077200000, 19.184281817226], [1201755600000, 19.691226605207], [1204261200000, 18.982314051295], [1206936000000, 18.707820309008], [1209528000000, 17.459630929761], [1212206400000, 16.500616076782], [1214798400000, 18.086324003979], [1217476800000, 18.929464156258], [1220155200000, 18.233728682084], [1222747200000, 16.315776297325], [1225425600000, 14.63289219025], [1228021200000, 14.667835024478], [1230699600000, 13.946993947308], [1233378000000, 14.394304684397], [1235797200000, 13.724462792967], [1238472000000, 10.930879035806], [1241064000000, 9.8339915513708], [1243742400000, 10.053858541872], [1246334400000, 11.786998438287], [1249012800000, 11.780994901769], [1251691200000, 11.305889670276], [1254283200000, 10.918452290083], [1256961600000, 9.6811395055706], [1259557200000, 10.971529744038], [1262235600000, 13.330210480209], [1264914000000, 14.592637568961], [1267333200000, 14.605329141157], [1270008000000, 13.936853794037], [1272600000000, 12.189480759072], [1275278400000, 11.676151385046], [1277870400000, 13.058852800017], [1280548800000, 13.62891543203], [1283227200000, 13.811107569918], [1285819200000, 13.786494560787], [1288497600000, 14.04516285753], [1291093200000, 13.697412447288], [1293771600000, 13.677681376221], [1296450000000, 19.961511864531], [1298869200000, 21.049198298158], [1301544000000, 22.687631094008], [1304136000000, 25.469010617433], [1306814400000, 24.883799437121], [1309406400000, 24.203843814248], [1312084800000, 22.138760964038], [1314763200000, 16.034636966228], [1317355200000, 15.394958944556], [1320033600000, 12.625642461969], [1322629200000, 12.973735699739], [1325307600000, 15.786018336149], [1327986000000, 15.227368020134], [1330491600000, 15.899752650734], [1333166400000, 18.994731295388], [1335758400000, 18.450055817702], [1338436800000, 17.863719889669]]
        },
        {
            "key": "Ethane",
            "values": [[1138683600000, 7.1590087090398], [1141102800000, 7.1297210970108], [1143781200000, 5.5774588290586], [1146369600000, 5.4977254491156], [1149048000000, 5.5138153113634], [1151640000000, 4.3198084032122], [1154318400000, 3.9179295839125], [1156996800000, 3.8110093051479], [1159588800000, 5.5629020916939], [1162270800000, 5.7241673711336], [1164862800000, 5.4715049695004], [1167541200000, 4.9193763571618], [1170219600000, 5.136053947247], [1172638800000, 5.1327258759766], [1175313600000, 5.1888943925082], [1177905600000, 5.5191481293345], [1180584000000, 5.6093625614921], [1183176000000, 4.2706312987397], [1185854400000, 4.4453235132117], [1188532800000, 4.6228003109761], [1191124800000, 5.0645764756954], [1193803200000, 5.0723447230959], [1196398800000, 5.1457765818846], [1199077200000, 5.4067851597282], [1201755600000, 5.472241916816], [1204261200000, 5.3742740389688], [1206936000000, 6.251751933664], [1209528000000, 6.1406852153472], [1212206400000, 5.8164385627465], [1214798400000, 5.4255846656171], [1217476800000, 5.3738499417204], [1220155200000, 5.1815627753979], [1222747200000, 5.0305983235349], [1225425600000, 4.6823058607165], [1228021200000, 4.5941481589093], [1230699600000, 5.4669598474575], [1233378000000, 5.1249037357], [1235797200000, 4.3504421250742], [1238472000000, 4.6260881026002], [1241064000000, 5.0140402458946], [1243742400000, 4.7458462454774], [1246334400000, 6.0437019654564], [1249012800000, 6.4595216249754], [1251691200000, 6.6420468254155], [1254283200000, 5.8927271960913], [1256961600000, 5.4712108838003], [1259557200000, 6.1220254207747], [1262235600000, 5.5385935169255], [1264914000000, 5.7383377612639], [1267333200000, 6.1715976730415], [1270008000000, 4.0102262681174], [1272600000000, 3.769389679692], [1275278400000, 3.5301571031152], [1277870400000, 2.7660252652526], [1280548800000, 3.1409983385775], [1283227200000, 3.0528024863055], [1285819200000, 4.3126123157971], [1288497600000, 4.594654041683], [1291093200000, 4.5424126126793], [1293771600000, 4.7790043987302], [1296450000000, 7.4969154058289], [1298869200000, 7.9424751557821], [1301544000000, 7.1560736250547], [1304136000000, 7.9478117337855], [1306814400000, 7.4109214848895], [1309406400000, 7.5966457641101], [1312084800000, 7.165754444071], [1314763200000, 5.4816702524302], [1317355200000, 4.9893656089584], [1320033600000, 4.498385105327], [1322629200000, 4.6776090358151], [1325307600000, 8.1350814368063], [1327986000000, 8.0732769990652], [1330491600000, 8.5602340387277], [1333166400000, 5.1293714074325], [1335758400000, 5.2586794619016], [1338436800000, 5.1100853569977]]
        },
        {
            "key": "Carbon Monoxide",
            "values": [[1138683600000, 13.242301508051], [1141102800000, 12.863536342042], [1143781200000, 21.034044171629], [1146369600000, 21.419084618803], [1149048000000, 21.142678863691], [1151640000000, 26.568489677529], [1154318400000, 24.839144939905], [1156996800000, 25.456187462167], [1159588800000, 26.350164502826], [1162270800000, 26.47833320519], [1164862800000, 26.425979547847], [1167541200000, 28.191461582256], [1170219600000, 28.930307448808], [1172638800000, 29.521413891117], [1175313600000, 28.188285966466], [1177905600000, 27.704619625832], [1180584000000, 27.490862424829], [1183176000000, 28.770679721286], [1185854400000, 29.060480671449], [1188532800000, 28.240998844973], [1191124800000, 33.004893194127], [1193803200000, 34.075180359928], [1196398800000, 32.548560664833], [1199077200000, 30.629727432728], [1201755600000, 28.642858788159], [1204261200000, 27.973575227842], [1206936000000, 27.393351882726], [1209528000000, 28.476095288523], [1212206400000, 29.29667866426], [1214798400000, 29.222333802896], [1217476800000, 28.092966093843], [1220155200000, 28.107159262922], [1222747200000, 25.482974832098], [1225425600000, 21.208115993834], [1228021200000, 20.295043095268], [1230699600000, 15.925754618401], [1233378000000, 17.162864628346], [1235797200000, 17.084345773174], [1238472000000, 22.246007102281], [1241064000000, 24.530543998509], [1243742400000, 25.084184918242], [1246334400000, 16.606166527358], [1249012800000, 17.239620011628], [1251691200000, 17.336739127379], [1254283200000, 25.478492475753], [1256961600000, 23.017152085245], [1259557200000, 25.617745423683], [1262235600000, 24.061133998642], [1264914000000, 23.223933318644], [1267333200000, 24.425887263937], [1270008000000, 35.501471156693], [1272600000000, 33.775013878676], [1275278400000, 30.417993630285], [1277870400000, 30.023598978467], [1280548800000, 33.327519522436], [1283227200000, 31.963388450371], [1285819200000, 30.498967232092], [1288497600000, 32.403696817912], [1291093200000, 31.47736071922], [1293771600000, 31.53259666241], [1296450000000, 41.760282761548], [1298869200000, 45.605771243237], [1301544000000, 39.986557966215], [1304136000000, 43.846330510051], [1306814400000, 39.857316881857], [1309406400000, 37.675127768208], [1312084800000, 35.775077970313], [1314763200000, 48.631009702577], [1317355200000, 42.830831754505], [1320033600000, 35.611502589362], [1322629200000, 35.320136981738], [1325307600000, 31.564136901516], [1327986000000, 32.074407502433], [1330491600000, 35.053013769976], [1333166400000, 26.434568573937], [1335758400000, 25.305617871002], [1338436800000, 24.520919418236]]
        }
    ];

    var colors = d3.scale.category20();

    var chart;
    nv.addGraph(function () {
        var width = 1360, height = 768;
        chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
            .x(function (d) { return d[0] })
            .y(function (d) { return d[1] })
            .controlLabels({ stacked: "Stacked" })
            .duration(300)
            .width(width).height(height);

        chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) { return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d)) });
        chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.4f'));

        chart.legend.vers('furious');

        d3.select('#chart1')
            .datum(data)
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .call(chart)
            .each('start', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    d3.selectAll('#chart1 *').each(function () {
                        if (this.__transition__)
                            this.__transition__.duration = 1;
                    })
                }, 0)
            });

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
        return chart;
    });
```

```css
.graph-box{
   display:block;
  height: 1000px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/novus/nvd3/master/build/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/novus/nvd3/master/build/nv.d3.js"></script>
<div class="graph-box">
            <svg id="chart1"></svg>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please I need your advice, it is critical issue for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
var upperLimit = 110;
chart.yDomain([0, upperLimit]);
chart.update();
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/18739949/2911452